# ERB not wanting to render file in Rack App

Tags: ruby, templates, rendering, rack, erb

When I use an erb method using:

```
require 'erb'

def erb(template)
  path = File.expand_path("../views/#{template}", __FILE__)
  ERB.new(File.read(path)).result(binding)
end
```

And afterward use a:

```
Rack::Response.new(erb('default.html.erb'))
```

It raises an Errno::ENOENT. Why is this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may have gotten your file path wrong. Check to make sure that's right.

Comment: Your right, it was looking for `lib/views` inside of my directory, two `../` made the difference.